# Binary Shift displaying different results in VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm really confused as to why the following code gives me different results when run in VB.NET as opposed to C#. I've read that there are some binary shift differences between the two languages but I can't work out what I need to do to make VB.NET show the same answer for 'pos' as C# does.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        MultiplyH({168, 238, 95, 83, 235, 11, 228, 190, 8, 58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})


    End Sub

    Public Sub MultiplyH(ByVal x As Byte())

        Dim pos As Integer = x(15) << 1
        Dim i = 14
        While i >= 0
            pos = x(i) << 1
            Interlocked.Decrement(i)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

The first eight answers for 'pos' are all the same (to be expected for the zeroes) but once i = 6, VB.NET shows pos = 124 whereas C# has pos = 380. Can anyone help me so that pos = 380 in VB.NET please?

The C# code, btw, is:

```
int pos = x[15] << 1;
for (int i = 14; i >= 0; --i)
{
                pos = x[i] << 1;
}
```

Comment: Byte only goes up to 255.  Why not operator on an array of integers instead?  I assume the difference here is the C# converts the byte value to an int before the shift while VB.Net does not.

Comment: pos = (x(i) << 1) And 255

Comment: Also I think you mean when i is 7 because it's the 190 that would left shift to 380

Comment: @jdweng You mean `pos = (x[i] << 1) & 255;` for C# to get it to result as 124.  The other way would be `x(i) As Integer << 1` (or however you cast in VB) to get the 380 result.

Comment: Thanks - I tried CInt (x(i) << 1 but it's still 124, not 380?

Comment: As for bytes, I was simplifying a wider problem - the bigger code I'm trying to fix passes bytes in rather than an array of integers.

Comment: Put `x(i)` into a temp integer first: `Dim xi As Integer = x(i)` and then shift `xi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for the C# `<<` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-):

> Because the shift operators are defined only for the int, uint, long, and ulong types, the result of an operation always contains at least 32 bits. **If the left-hand operand is of another integral type (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char), its value is converted to the int type**

[Emphasis mine.]

From the [documentation for the VB.NET `<<` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator):

> The result always has the same data type as that of the expression being shifted.

To get the same result in VB.NET as in C#, you need to use:

```
pos = CInt(x(i)) << 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried CInt but wrapping the whole expression rather than just the x(I) - that worked perfectly. Thanks again for this and the explanation